# Would NTFS Compression actually speed up the use of USB flash drives?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, compression, bitrate

When using NTFS on USB flash drives, would using NTFS compression make them faster?

With fast processors and limited USB bit rate, it seems feasible that it might, and would also have the benefit of more capacity.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do with the data.  For simple reads - providing you have the right program(s) - it could indeed make them faster.  When you need to start writing - all bets are off.  Sounds like time for some benchmarks...